# windows 8.1 kiosk mode - Stream to TV

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, kiosk-mode

I am building a modern application on Windows 8.1. This application will display a list of videos. A user can select a video to start playing it. This application will run in Kiosk mode using Assigned Access feature of Windows 8.1 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/hyperyash/archive/2013/10/25/enable-kiosk-mode-in-windows-8-1.aspx

Now that I have the app running in kiosk mode, I want to stream it automatically to a Smart TV. I have looked at the Play To contract in Windows 8.1 but all of these require user initiated action by tapping on Devices in Charms bar. How can I stream the video to the TV - is there a way to achieve this through code?

Comment: were you able to find a solution to this? I am struggling with a similar issue myself trying to grammatically start an audio stream using play to.